# elif command is throwing error

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Hi is the below `elif` command correct?

```
elif [[ "${FILECOMMAND}" = "" ] && [[ -f ${ZIPFILE} ]||[ -f ${ZIPFILE3} ]]]
```

I am getting an error when I run it.

Comment: Hi and welcome the the site. When asking about errors, please show us the error. Also, always mention 1) the operating system you are using and 2) the shell you are using. The syntax error here is obvious but next time it might depend on these details.

Comment: @terdon : sure going ahead will give the details

Answer (score 3):

If you use the bash tests `[[` use it everywhere, you missed one, and some others are misplaced.

What I would do :

```
elif [[ "${FILECOMMAND}" ]] || [[ -f "${ZIPFILE}" || -f "${ZIPFILE3}" ]]
```

Comment: Hi I want to use and condition - elif [[ "${FILECOMMAND}" ]] && [[ -f "${ZIPFILE}" || -f "${ZIPFILE3}" ]] ..  will it work? and thanks for your help

Comment: I use **OR** `||` here, because I test if the variable is void or not. You can use **AND** if you want with `[[ ! "${FILECOMMAND}" ]]`